# Kubeflow ssl: none from centraldashboard to profiles which cause rbac access denied

Tags: istio, kubeflow

**Background**
We install kubeflow:v1.8.0 and an individual istio:1.20.3.

**Issue**
When we use DEX to do OIDC authentication and login kubeflow successfully, it will got a rbac access denied error in UI.

We enable RBAC debug log and get log info from profiles-kfam pod.
`istioctl pc log --level "rbac:debug" profiles-kfam-*.kubeflow` 
`k logs -f profiles-kfam-*`
Then find out that's because traffic from centraldashboard to profiles without ssl and not able to get principals info(cluster.local/ns/kubeflow/sa/centraldashboard) so the authorizationpolicy** profiles-kfam** doesn't work.

Any idea how to fix this issue?